# Name of Current App in Google App Engine (Java)

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Using the Google App Engine Java API, is there a way to access the name of the currently running application i.e. the application name specified in your `appengine-web.xml` file ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get appname (without appspot.com and version) via [`SystemProperty.applicationId.get()`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/utils/SystemProperty#applicationIdhttp://).

Answer (score 1):

`ApiProxy.Environment.getAppId()` - see AppIdentity service https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/appidentity/overview

Comment: This will give full hostname, i.e. 2.appname.appspot.com